# EntityManager is null in DAO class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to build an application with Java Spring and hibernate.
For the dao classes I'm using the generic dao pattern. When I try to execute a query a nullpointer exception is thrown because the entityManager is null. I think it's not injected properly but I don't know why.

Application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id = "klantDao" class="service.JpaKlantDao"/>
    <bean id="userDao" class="service.JpaUserDao"/>
    <bean id="assembler" class="service.Assembler" />
</beans>
```

Dispatcher servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="service"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/CentricJavaDB"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" /> 
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/> 
             </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class=" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager ">
        <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="mymessages" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!--Spring Security Configuration-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>overzicht.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The controller where I inject the dao:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private KlantDao klantDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String klantInloggen(Model model) 
    {
        String k;
        k = klantDao.findAll().get(0).getEmailadres();
        return "login";
    }
}
```

The generic dao interface:

```
public interface GenericDao<T> {

    public List<T> findAll();
    public T update(T object);
    public T get(Long id);
    public void delete(T object);
    public void insert(T object);
    public boolean exists(Long id) ;
}
```

The generic dao implementation:

```
@Transactional
public class JpaGenericDao<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

    private Class<T> type;

    private EntityManager em;

    public JpaGenericDao(Class<T> type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public T get(Long id) {
        T entity = this.em.find(this.type, id);
        return entity;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return this.em.createQuery(
                "select entity from " + this.type.getName() + " entity").getResultList();
    }

    //@Transactional
    @Override
    public void insert(T object) {
        em.persist(object);
    }

    //@Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(T object) {
        em.remove(em.merge(object));
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public boolean exists(Long id) {
        T entity = this.em.find(this.type, id);
        return entity != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T object) {
        return em.merge(object);
    }
}
```

The Klant dao interface:

```
public interface KlantDao
{       
    public List<Klant> findAll();       
}
```

The klant dao implementation:

```
public class JpaKlantDao extends JpaGenericDao<Klant> implements KlantDao
{
    public JpaKlantDao()
    {
        super(Klant.class);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me, I've been debugging for hours and I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: AFAIK, the datasource, transaction manager and entity manager factory beans should be defined in the main application context, where the DAOs are defined, and not in the child dispatcher servlet context.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you, but Spring wouldn't just let an injectable field be `null`. It would throw exceptions if it couldn't autowire something.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I would agree for a field injected with `@Autowired`, but I'm not sure that the same rule applies for a field injected with `@PersistenceContext`.

Comment: @JBNizet I moved the datasource, transaction manager and entity manager factory beans to the application context and the problem is the same. Is the sequence of the beans important?

Comment: Also remove `<context:component-scan base-package="service"/>` since services are defined in the main context.

Comment: @JB Spring uses a `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to inject `@PersistenceContext` annotated members. The javadoc states `A default PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor will be registered
 by the "context:annotation-config" and "context:component-scan" XML tags.` Looking at the source code, it will throw `BeanCreationException`.

Comment: So, the component-scan or annotation-config should be in the main context as well.

Comment: I would think whichever context is processing `JpaGenericDao` or `JpaKlantDao` should have it.